# How to fix "Trainer: evaluation requires an eval_dataset" in Huggingface Transformers?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model, huggingface-trainer

I’m trying to do a finetuning without an evaluation dataset.
For that, I’m using the following code:

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=resume_from_checkpoint,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
)
def compute_metrics(pred: EvalPrediction):
    labels = pred.label_ids
    preds = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)
    f1 = f1_score(labels, preds, average="weighted")
    acc = accuracy_score(labels, preds, average="weighted")
    return {"accuracy": acc, "f1": f1}
trainer = Trainer(
    model=self.nli_model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

However, I get

```
ValueError: Trainer: evaluation requires an eval_dataset
```

I thought that by default, Trainer does no evaluation… at least in the docs, I got this idea…

Answer (score 7):

I set `evaluation_strategy="no"` and `do_eval=False` when setting the `TrainingArguments` and then I was able to call the `trainer.train()` without passing any eval dataset.
Note, I tested this on `transformers` version `4.31.0`

Comment: This way the evaluation will be bypassed, which is not a good practice. alvas' answer must be the accepted one.

Comment: I agree that bypassing validation evaluation is not a good practice. Still, if that is what the user specifically needs, they should be aware that it is possible to achieve the same.

Comment: @SarahMasud is the one that should be accepted, since it is actually answering the question.

Answer (score 4):

First do this [Splitting dataset into Train, Test and Validation using HuggingFace Datasets functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001128/splitting-dataset-into-train-test-and-validation-using-huggingface-datasets-fun/76223302#76223302)

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from datasets import DatasetDict

...

# Split dataset into 80-20%
ds_train, ds_valid = tokenized_datasets.train_test_split(test_size=0.2, seed=42)
```

Then

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=self.nli_model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=ds_train,
    eval_dataset=ds_valid,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

It is important to understand why when "training" you will always need a "validation" set.

The `train_dataset` changes the gradient during optimization and parameters of the model. Reports training loss.

The `eval_dataset` is sort of like a validation (aka development set) to validate the results of the model updates independent of the data it is trained on. Reports validation loss.

Comment: This is not what the user ask, they simply wanted to know how to prevent HF's Trainer from launching evaluation, which would inevitably fail with no data provided. Yet again a"I know better what the user needs" StackOverflow answer.

Comment: This is not the answer the OP asked for, but this is the answer that the OP needed!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looking through source code here: [Source Huggingface Trainer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.4.0/_modules/transformers/trainer.html)

We see the following error in `get_eval_dataloader()` function

```
if eval_dataset is None and self.eval_dataset is None:
   raise ValueError("Trainer: evaluation requires an eval_dataset.")
```

so it seems you need an eval_dataset passed in the `__init__` (where you call trainer=Trainer(...) or eventually because `predict()` calls `evaluate()` which calls `get_eval_dataloader()`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply avoid this error by commenting out the evaluation_strategy="epoch" line. It worked for me on transformers 4.37.2

please see the documentation below:

evaluation_strategy (str or IntervalStrategy, optional, defaults to "no") — The evaluation strategy to adopt during training. Possible values are:
"no": No evaluation is done during training.
"steps": Evaluation is done (and logged) every eval_steps.
"epoch": Evaluation is done at the end of each epoch.